# ORA-12514 TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, listener, tnsnames

Already read all the question related to this error, but couldnt resolve the issue.

As of yesterday, the oracle SMALLWORLD service has stopped working and the error is

> ORA-12514 TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

the following are the system information to better understand the situation:

LISTENER.ORA content :[Listener.ora](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2sum.png)

TNSNAMES.ORA content :[TNSNAMES.ORA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOiYH.png)

SQLNET.ORA content   :[SQLNET.ORA CONTENT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Crv2k.png)

the following is the result of

> LSNRCTL SERVICES

command.

[LSNRCTL.SERVICES result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Edje.png)

as you can see the service name ATTACHMENTDB is recognisable, but service SMALLWORLD is not.

while trying to logon with sysdba, the result is

> ORA-01017 invalid user name/password; logon denied

while trying to logon with SYSTEM user, the result is

> ORA-01034 : ORACLE not available

and

> ORA-27101 : shared memory realm does not exist

below image, is the result of SQLPLUS /NOLOG command

[SQLPLUS /NOLOG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIOxV.png)

i already tried stopping and starting the ORACLE services and the Listener in the SERVICES.MSC, but nothing worked.
i don't understand why ATTACHMENTDB service works but not the SMALLWORLD service.

any hint appreciated.

Comment: [Please post text rather than images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Are these two service names for the same DB, or (more likely) two DBs? It sounds like that DB just isn't running; after `/nolog` you still have to `connect / as sysdba` before trying to start it. And that assumes your environemt is set up right for that DB. If it's failing to start automatically, though, you can look at the alert log to see why. (This is all off-topic for this site though...)

Comment: Thanks alex for reply, connect / as sysdba gave me the same err " insufficent privileges"

Comment: update, Problem solved. Thanks to Mr.Shahram Abedini and Specially Mr.Bahadori for solving this. Apparently flash recovery area run out of space and oracle crashed. actually there was 2 problem, one that listener didnt know the service which we had to create a new SPFILESMALLWORLD.ORA file, after restarting the service,listener did know the service but still couldnt log on to the oracle because of insufficient privileges, after making sure that everything was ok in the operating system level, we had to create a fresh PWDsmallworld.ORA file. this solved the issue and we logged on to the system.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem in windows 10 and Oracle19C.
You should try the following ways and one of them may work for you.

Way-1: In windows: use this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOTwdaI_05A): restart services `OracleOraDB19Home1TNSListener` then `OracleServiceORCL`.

Way-2: connect with `system` user password to `sql plus` as shown as:

```
Enter user-name: system/ as sysdba
Enter password: your_password

SQL> shutdown
SQL> startup nomount
SQL> alter system set db_recovery_file_dest_size=4G scope=both;
SQL> alter database mount;
SQL> alter database open;
```

And now check your problem fixed? If no set below code then check again.

```
SQL> alter system set local_listener='(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)   (HOST=127.0.0.1) (PORT=1521)))';
```

This work for me.